# Why coredns in Kubernetes can't resolve Pod DNS Records

Tags: kubernetes

```
ytong@controller-4135505:~/cka$ cat 14.15-pod.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busy33
  labels:
    app: 14-15
spec:
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
  hostname: 14-15
  subdomain: ytong82
  containers:
  - name: busybox-container
    image: busybox
    command: ['sleep', '3600']
```

```
ytong@controller-4135505:~/cka$ kubectl get pods -o wide | grep busy33
busy33                     1/1     Running     0          91s     10.36.0.1   worker3-4135521   <none>           <none>
```

I try to resolve its pod DNS records like below

```
ytong@controller-4135505:~/cka$ kubectl exec -it busy33 -- nslookup -type=a 10-36-0-1.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10:53

** server can't find 10-36-0-1.default.svc.cluster.local: NXDOMAIN

command terminated with exit code 1
ytong@controller-4135505:~/cka$ kubectl exec -it busy33 -- nslookup -type=a 14-15.ytong82.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10:53

** server can't find 14-15.ytong82.default.svc.cluster.local: NXDOMAIN

command terminated with exit code 1
```

Neither of above commands work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use image `busybox:1.28` instead of other images as those images has got DNS resolution issue.

When you are trying to do DNS resolution using pod you need to use below command which has `pod` instead of `svc`

```
kubectl exec -it busy33 -- nslookup 10-36-0-1.default.pod.cluster.local
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace svc.cluster.local with pod.cluster.local and it works for resolve pod DNS name by ip address

```
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      10-36-0-1.default.pod.cluster.local
Address 1: 10.36.0.1 busy33
```